# Laravel 9: Why does sail up not end?

Tags: laravel

I have problem to install a laravel app according to the Getting Started guide for laravel 9.

After starting the sail up command (./vendor/bin/sail up) it runs now for over 3 hours. the last logs are:

```
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:43:26Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55080 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000061

my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:43:56Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55084 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000055
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:44:27Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55088 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000053
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:44:57Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55092 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000054
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:45:27Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55096 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000101
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:45:57Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55100 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000063
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:46:27Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55104 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000068
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:46:57Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55108 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000066
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:47:27Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55112 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000069
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:47:58Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55116 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000050
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:48:28Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55120 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000044
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:48:58Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55124 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000048
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:49:28Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55128 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000072
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:49:58Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55132 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000038
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:50:29Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55136 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000048
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:50:59Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55140 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000046
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:51:29Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55144 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000040
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:51:59Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55148 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000039
my-app-laravel.test-1  | [Fri Mar  4 23:52:12 2022] 172.18.0.1:41200 Accepted
my-app-laravel.test-1  | [Fri Mar  4 23:52:17 2022] 172.18.0.1:41200 Closing
my-app-laravel.test-1  | [Fri Mar  4 23:52:17 2022] 172.18.0.1:41204 Accepted
my-app-laravel.test-1  | [Fri Mar  4 23:52:17 2022] 172.18.0.1:41204 [200]: GET /favicon.ico
my-app-laravel.test-1  | [Fri Mar  4 23:52:17 2022] 172.18.0.1:41204 Closing
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:52:30Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55160 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000064
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:53:01Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55164 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000066
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:53:31Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55168 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000049
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:54:01Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55172 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000038
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:54:31Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55176 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000040
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:55:01Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55180 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000041
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:55:32Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55184 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000042
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:56:02Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55188 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000046
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:56:32Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55192 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000043
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:57:02Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55196 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000110
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:57:32Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55200 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000044
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:58:02Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55204 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000039
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:58:33Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55208 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000038
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:59:03Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55212 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000108
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-04T23:59:34Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55216 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000048
my-app-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
my-app-meilisearch-1   | [2022-03-05T00:00:05Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1:55220 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000057
```

All the messages are repeating again and again. Is this a normal duration for the script?

Comment: Sail up runs the docker container the logs are normal. You have to shut down the docker if you don’t need it anymore by either sail down or cmd+c in terminal

Comment: @Luckyfella Laravel 9 docs say "Once the application's Docker containers have been started, you can access the application in your web browser at: http://localhost.". I have the same problem than the OP and was never able to access http://localhost .

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler After you run sail up in terminal - do you get any error messages? When running other applications like mamp or webpack at the same time it can happen that port for exampleb are already in use. Just the first comming into my mind

Answer (score 1):

You are running the docker container with Sail cli

The missing part is

> -d

(Docker detached mode) which is used to run the container in the background

```
docker up -d
```

In your case `./vendor/bin/sail up -d`

Just google
**Docker detached mode**

Answer (score 0):

Just run it with `-d` flag for detached. Sail aliased `docker-compose` command.

i.e. `./vendor/bin/sail up -d`

See the full list of options here.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/