# Laravel 8 install - sail up hangs at mailhog/meilisearch - no phpmyadmin if ctrl-c

Tags: php, laravel, installation

I have installed a clean Monterey on my Mac and now Laravel 9.  I followed the instruction in the docs but [sail up] does not stop to throw lines after lines in termional.  I saw in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71358508/laravel-9-why-does-sail-up-not-end) that this was normal.  So I exit with ctrl-c.  In Docker Desktop, the container example-app is there but what is the next step?

I see that the docker-compose.yml file does not have phpMyAdmin.  Was it installed?  Where is it?  How do I access it?  Before Monterey, I installed Laravel 8 with brew and composer and I could access it with pma.test in the browser...

Also how do I access the project in the browser?  I used to type example-app.test to view it...

I need help to figure out the next steps.

docker-composere.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local
```

[image: example-app in Docker screenshot]

docker ps results

```
paul@MBP-Paul Sites % docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                  PORTS                                            NAMES
90274792c508   sail-8.1/app                  "start-container"        18 hours ago   Up 18 hours             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 8000/tcp                     example-app_laravel.test_1
904074d309de   mysql/mysql-server:8.0        "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   18 hours ago   Up 18 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp          example-app_mysql_1
d1d7d685c090   selenium/standalone-chrome    "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   18 hours ago   Up 18 hours             4444/tcp, 5900/tcp                               example-app_selenium_1
c98e1ba83569   mailhog/mailhog:latest        "MailHog"                18 hours ago   Up 18 hours             0.0.0.0:1025->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp   example-app_mailhog_1
414d916be277   redis:alpine                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 hours ago   Up 18 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                           example-app_redis_1
a384df0d281c   getmeili/meilisearch:latest   "tini -- /bin/sh -c …"   18 hours ago   Up 18 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:7700->7700/tcp                           example-app_meilisearch_1
```

Comment: If it is properly installed you can use sail like a docker. Phpmyadmin is a db tool but related to laravel. You can use docker commands like sail ps just write sail instead of docker. Can you share docker compose yml and sail ps result or docker desktop image for your app

Comment: Thank you @gguney.  I have edited my post with what you requested.